# Replace a PHP string into dynamic select box

Tags: string, replace, dynamic

I have a string like
`$srr = 'Mechanical engineering was at the heart of {} Taylor's theorizing, providing {} the context for its development, the world view by which it was sustained and, finally, the justification for its widespread application.';`

And I need to convert every `{}` into HTML `select`, and `option` value will be dynamic that I am going to fetch from DB. 
My problem is, when I am trying to replace `{}` into select box,
`str_replace` does not allow me to add foreach loop.
I am using `array_chunk() ( $fouroptions = array_chunk($options,4); )` to divide options into 4,
and I want to replace `{}` into option values that I got using `array_chunk()`.
and I got Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
            [2] => C
            [3] => D
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => E
            [1] => F
            [2] => G
            [3] => H
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => I
            [1] => J
            [2] => K
            [3] => L
        )
)
```

Here is my php code:

```
$fouroptions = array_chunk($options,4);
$loop = count($fouroptions); 
for ($row = 0; $row < $loop; $row++)
{
    $testselect= "<select>";
    for ($col = 0; $col < 4; $col++)
    {
        $testselect .= "<option>".$fouroptions[$row][$col]."</option>";
    }
    $testselect .= "</select>";
    echo $string = str_replace("{}", $testselect, $quiz_question['title']);
}
```

Comment: Here is my php code <?php $fouroptions = array_chunk($options,4);  
   $loop =  count($fouroptions);
   
}
   for ($row = 0; $row < $loop; $row++) {

  $testselect=  "<select>";
  for ($col = 0; $col < 4; $col++) {
    $testselect .= "<option>".$fouroptions[$row][$col]."</option>";
  }
  $testselect .= "</select>";
  
 
 echo $string = str_replace("{}", $testselect, $quiz_question['title']);
} 
  ?>

Comment: Got this result when i am using array_chunk()                                                          Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
            [2] => C
            [3] => D
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => E
            [1] => F
            [2] => G
            [3] => H
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => I
            [1] => J
            [2] => K
            [3] => L
        )

)

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Are you trying to have the user make a series of selections, and then you return the final string, like a MadLib?  Or are you trying to display exactly that sentence, but with the {} replaced by a selection box?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you're after.  I copy the text into a string.  Then, each time through the loop, I use `str_replace` to replace ONE instance of {}.  The next loop will replace the next one, and so on.

```
<?php
$fouroptions = array_chunk($options,4);
$loop = count($fouroptions); 
$string = $quiz_question['title'];
for ($row = 0; $row < $loop; $row++)
{
    $testselect= "<select>";
    for ($col = 0; $col < 4; $col++)
    {
        $testselect .= "<option>".$fouroptions[$row][$col]."</option>";
    }
    $testselect .= "</select>";
    $string = str_replace("{}", $testselect, $string, 1);
}
echo $string;
?>
```

So, this will look like:

```
Mechanical engineering was at the heart of [A v] Taylor's theorizing, providing [E v] the context for its development, the world view by which it was sustained and, finally, the justification for its widespread application.
```

where `[A v]` is trying to represent a pulldown combo box with the A selected.